# Sub query with aggregate function

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, max, aggregate

I'm having trouble getting the correct records. My location table records the history of locations a piece of equipment has been. Thus, the latest date_moved will be its current location. The location table currently consists of 2258 records (“state_tag” is FK). In my equipment table, I have 2050 pieces of equipment each with a unique “state_tag” number (PK). So, what I want is to query the location table to get the current location of all the equipment (i.e. MAX(date_moved). The query then should return 2050 records.

Following the example of a previous post, I have tried the following query:

`SELECT * FROM its_locations WHERE date_moved in (SELECT MAX(date_moved) FROM its_locations GROUP BY state_tag);`

However, the query is returning 2257 records when it should return 2050 records. Obviously, my query is doing exactly as written, but not as wanted (lol).

I also tried the following query which gave me 2050 records, but only returned the first record from each group and inserted the max date of the group into that record which most likely will not be its current location.

`SELECT state_tag
, MAX(date_moved) AS "Date Moved"
, building
, room
, staff
, comments
FROM its_locations 
GROUP BY state_tag;`

Please help me with the correct query.

Thanks very much in advance.

Chris

Comment: You should tag the question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM its_locations
WHERE date_moved in (SELECT MAX(date_moved) FROM its_locations GROUP BY state_tag)
```

The subquery calculates the maximum `date_moved` for all locations.  Then it returns *any* location that has those dates.  So, two locations might be moving on the same date, one is a maximum date, and both are returned.

What you want is a correlated subquery, not `group by`:

```
SELECT l.*
FROM its_locations l
WHERE date_moved = (SELECT MAX(l2.date_moved)
                    FROM its_locations l2
                    WHERE l2.state_tag = l.state_tag
                   );
```

You may still get more than 2,050 rows, if the original table has duplicates.  But this will probably solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you Gordon! I just completed a class "Introduction to SQL programming" and was looking at correlated subqueries but couldn't frame my thoughts into a statement. Many thanks.